# Domain backslash in Git URL

Tags: ansible

When I try to clone a repo using windows domain credentials the backslashes are removed.

```
git: repo="http://DOMAIN\\user:password@server/repo"
     dest=/srv/clone
     version=develop
```

The error:

```
failed: [x.x.x.x] => {"cmd": ["/usr/bin/git", "ls-remote", "http://DOMAINuser:password@server/repo", "-h", "refs/heads/develop"], "failed": true, "rc": 128} 
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://DOMAINuser:password@server/repo/'

msg: fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://DOMAINuser:password@server/repo/'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

It looks like the escape is not working?

Comment: It never hurts to try the same thing in strict YAML.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, active directory authentication is orthogonal to the auth scheme you can use with the HTTP method in git. Thus, `DOMAIN\\USER` is simply the user string that your HTTP client (in your case, `git`) sends to the server. `\` might look strange to the client, though. Have you tried `\\\\`?

Comment: But if I use 'git clone http://DOMAIN\\user:password@server/repo' it works, so I think the problem is within ansible. I didn't find any topic about this.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem funny, but I've lost enough time with Ansible escaping to justify it. Try defining a var (in some constant-appropriate place) like this `backslash: "\\"` and use it in templates like this, `backslash*2`.

At the very least you get consistency among direct uses in `"{{ .. }}"` and indirect uses in filters, like `"{{ ... | some_filter('...') }}`.